# I am getting an empty file (Subset_soil_param.txt file) in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and to this forum, so I need some help with the following code:

```
original_soil_parameter_file = open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\original_soil_param.txt', "r")
Grid_Cell_id = open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\Grid_Cells.txt', "r")
Subset_soil_param = open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\subset_soil_param.txt', "w")
with open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\original_soil_param.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(' ')
        if a[1] == Grid_Cell_id:
            Subset_soil_param.write(line)
Subset_soil_param.close()
```

Basically, I have an original file (variable original_soil_parameter_file), which covers the whole North Western United States. And I want to subset the file based on my area. The original file contains rows of values with each values separated by a space. In order to subset I provided another text file to the code and called it Grid_cell_id. Then I used the for loop to match the second value (a[1]) with the values in Grid_Cell_id, so that after a finding an identical grid cell id in both files, the code will start saving the lines in the new file named Subset_soil_param.txt. After I run code, the Subset_soil_param is created but it's empty. I get the following output, and the console nothing else and the file is empty, but the code does generate the subset_soil_param.txt file (which is empty).

```
runfile('D:/Spring 2020/VIC/Parameter_files/subset_soil_param.py', wdir='D:/Spring 2020/VIC/Parameter_files')
```

A sample from the original file:

```
1 240493 41.21875 -116.21875 0.1000 0.767791 0.400832 0.673064 2 13.6030 13.6030 13.6030 473.0640 473.0640 473.0640 -99 -99 -99 21.4270 64.2820 214.2750 1821.3800 0.1000 0.3000 0.7118 6.0880 4.0000 11.1500 11.1500 11.1500 0.4100 0.4100 0.4100 1485.7000 1485.7000 1485.7000 2620.2800 2620.2800 2620.2800 -8 0.3920 0.3920 0.3920 0.2560 0.2560 0.2560 0.0100 0.0300 458.8940 0 0 0 0 19.0384
```

Sample from the Grid_Cells.txt file:

```
288832
287904
287909
240493
```

Comment: `a[1] == Grid_Cell_id` compares a string with a file object which will never be true.

Comment: `cellid = a[1]`
Will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting a road block when checking if there is a match. You're doing this;

```
if '240493' == Grid_Cell_id:
```

The issue here, is that `Grid_Cell_id` is a file type, it isn't actually what you're trying to compare. This causes you to always return `false`.

```
type(Grid_Cell_id)
#<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
#<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\users\\admin\\desktop\\test.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

We can solve this by storing the contents of `Grid_Cell_id` as a list.

```
Grid_Cell_id = open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\Grid_Cells.txt', "r")
Grid_Cell_id = list(Grid_Cell_id)

#You could also do;

Grid_Cell_id = list(open('D:\Spring 2020\VIC\Parameter_files\Grid_Cells.txt', "r"))
```

Now that you have your grid cells stored in a list, you can call;

```
if a[1] in Grid_Cell_id:
```

This will return `True` if the value is found and `False` if not found.

EDIT:

This code is working on my system;

```
Grid_Cell_id = list(open('Grid_Cell_id.txt', "r"))   

with open('original_soil_parameter_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(' ')
        if a[1] in Grid_Cell_id:
            with open('subset_soil_param.txt', "w") as output:
                output.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am still getting an empty file.

Comment: Check my edit.. I have tested and confirmed the code is working correctly. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I am still getting an empty file, can you guide me on how to put the whole code in the comment?

Comment: Take the last snippet of code in my answer, save it as a `.py` file and then update file locations, based on the examples you provided the above should work.

Comment: Do I need to update file locations if the both the files and the script are in the same folder?

Comment: For some reason I am still getting an empty file, this is the code:
```Grid_Cell_id = list(open('Grid_Cells.txt', "r"))
Subset_soil_param = open('subset_soil_param.txt', "w")


with open('original_soil_param.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(' ')
        if a[1] in Grid_Cell_id:
            Subset_soil_param.write(line)

Subset_soil_param.close()
```
I am sorry,  but I can't seem to put the code as a block

Comment: Could you add `print('Match Found!')` just after `Subset_soil_param.write(line)` with the same indentation and let me know if anything prints?

Comment: It's printing Match Found!

Comment: I have updated my final block of code again, could you try with the updated code?

Comment: This code is not even generating an output file, I tried restarting Spyder and saving the new code in a new file, but the code won't generate a file.

Comment: I honestly would not be able to help any further. I am unsure on the differences with Spyder and native python. Every example i have provided worked for me on Windows 10, Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.5.

Comment: That's alright, thank you for you help and time, I am also using Python 3.7.3. I'll figure something out. And since your code works on your system, I'll mark the code as the answer.